# Why would the second time using a search cause it to stop the drop down list?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a jQuery drop down list that uses first CARS then secondly, the models from that car. Then, when the second choice is made - hit a submit button and search for the tire that the car uses. It works great the first time, but the second time, it stops and I have to reload the page to get it to work again. Any ideas of why this is happening would be helpful. My code example is here:

[Accessing a variable from inside a jquery drop down list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179612/accessing-a-variable-from-inside-a-jquery-drop-down-list)

Here is the code that searches:

```
function findtire() {
    global $db;
    if (isset($_POST['car'])) {
        $_SESSION['car'] = $_POST['car'];
        $car = $_SESSION['car'];
    }

    if (isset($car)) {
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT idtires FROM vehicle WHERE idcarmodel = '$car'");
        $query->execute();
        $tire = $query->fetchAll();
    }

    if (isset($tire)) {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($tire as $name) {
            echo "<li id='tiresearch'>";
            echo "Tire Size is Available: " . $name['idtires'];
            echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you getting while you search for second time ?

Comment: @regina-shephrd-riddle Is it second dynamically load on page?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen, I don't get any error, it just won't reload the second drop down list.

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura, It is jquery and it dynamically loads on page but has a search with a submit button and the second drop down list doesn't load after the first search.

Comment: Put some dummy value in the else part and whether it is coming to else part

Comment: @ReginaShepherdRiddle i think you should use Ajax for dynamic load

Comment: Your code also is open to injections you need to separate user input from SQL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php